# To multipart or not to multipart in ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq

I am designing a server application that will talk ZeroMQ. Without going into the nitty gritty details, the server will store and serve (from query requests) `(eventid, eventstring)` tuples.

My questions concerns design of the wire protocol. I would like to send my tuple from one end to another. I see two options:

- Serialize my tuple (using protobuf or whatever) and send it as a single message.
- Send my tuple as a multipart message; first part contains eventid and second contains eventstring.

**Are any of these two options preferable over the other?** Reading the [The ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall), there's a [chapter on Advanced Request-Reply patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#toc45) that uses multipart message envelopes heavily. Does this mean that I, as a user, should try to stick to single message to enable more advanced message patterns in the future?

Answer (score 2):

There's a section in the Guide that discusses serialization:

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Serializing-Your-Data

Your case with two fields is so trivial it doesn't IMO matter what format you use as long as it works.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at the wire protocol for the [Majordomo protocol](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:7). You can see from that example that each "field" in a structure is sent as a separate frame. This works quite well and is well supported.

You could also define a byte layout and send your data as a single frame. You will need to deal with any endian issues (if you are running code on platforms that are little and big endian) but that's fairly easy to deal with. If you don't know how, then use the frame technique like Majordomo.

There will be a negligible performance different between using 1 frame versus multiple frames. Unless you are sending gigabits per second, it's unlikely to be an issue. As always, benchmark to measure your specific case before you "optimize" and waste a bunch of time & effort to save 200 nanoseconds per message.